# Discord.py | How to write multiple events with the same name?

Tags: discord.py

Iv'e been trying to create 3 on_raw_reaction_add commands,  but only the one positioned last works(doesn't matter which one I put last).
Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload4: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
  message_id = payload4.message_id
  if message_id == 921150661456986122:
    if payload4.emoji.name == '**':
      
      guild_id = payload4.guild_id
      guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
      channel = guild.get_channel(921114527075020841)
      message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
      server = message.guild.owner
      await server.send(f'''{payload4.member.mention} asked for the ** role.''')
      user = client.get_user(payload4.user_id)
      emoji = client.get_emoji(767057115306655775)
      await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload3: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
  message_id = payload3.message_id
  if payload3.emoji.name == '*':
    
    guild_id = payload3.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    channel = guild.get_channel(921114527075020841)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    server = message.guild.owner
    await server.send(f'''{payload3.member.mention} asked for the * role.''')
    user = client.get_user(payload3.user_id)
    emoji = client.get_emoji(767057122054635540)
    await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload2: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
  message_id = payload2.message_id
  if message_id == 921114830356762666:
    
    guild_id = payload2.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    if payload2.emoji.name == 'vip':
      channel = guild.get_channel(921114527075020841)
      message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
      server = message.guild.owner
      await server.send(f'''{payload2.member.mention} asked for the vip role.''')
      user = client.get_user(payload2.user_id)
      emoji = client.get_emoji(767064946919735298)
      await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
```

I thought of maybe changing the first 2 events to "bot" and "cord" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make multiple events, you can though make multiple listeners!

```py
@client.listen('on_raw_reaction_add')
async def my_cool_function(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    # ... do something

@client.listen('on_raw_reaction_add')
async def my_second_cool_function(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    # ... do something else

# or

@client.listen()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    # ... do something


@client.listen()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    # ... do something else
```

You can only have a total of 25 listeners.

Comment: Thanks! It still doesn't work though... maybe I did something wrong. And I take the info from different payloads because I need different emojis and messages. Should it still work this way?

Comment: Update: everything works now!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can't have multiple functions with the same name, so you can't have multiple events with the same name. As Rose mentioned, if you really want to have the code in different functions, for example because they are in different files, you can use listeners. But if you have these functions in one file, or you hit the limit of 25 listeners, you should add all the code in one function:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 921150661456986122:
        #add the code that is inside the if in the first function here, but rename payload4 to payload
    if payload.emoji.name == '*':
        #add the code that is inside the if in the second function here, but rename payload3 to payload
    if message_id == 921114830356762666:
        #add the code that is inside the if in the third function here, but rename payload2 to payload
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have several payloads because I need it for several emojis and messages, so I can't put it under the same event. Unless there's a way to get information from a different payload in the middle. Is there?

Comment: Yeah, but `payload` is "updated" every time the event is called, so the payload can have all the different emojis and messages, and always has the message and emoji it happened for.